# Writing 32 Bit Data value SPI NXP K66

Tags: microcontroller, spi, nxp

How would I send 32bit data values using SPI of K66.. here is my attempt. The problem is only some parts of the 32bits are shown in the scope

```
status_t ADF4158_GenericWriteReg(pll_register_t reg, pll_params_t *params)
{
    dspi_command_data_config_t command;
    uint32_t value;

    if(reg >= kPLL_MAX)
        return kStatus_Fail;

    /* obtain formatted register value */
    value = ADF4158_GetFormattedRegValue(reg, params);

    PRINTF("Writing Register R%d with value 0x%08X\r\n", reg, value);

    /* Define Chip Select  */
    command.whichCtar = spiCtar;
    command.whichPcs = spiPcs;
    command.isPcsContinuous = true;
    command.isEndOfQueue = false;
    command.clearTransferCount = false;

    /* upper 16 bit */
    DSPI_MasterWriteDataBlocking(spiBase, &command, (uint16_t)(value >> 16U));

    /* lower 16 bit */
    command.isPcsContinuous = false;
    DSPI_MasterWriteDataBlocking(spiBase, &command, (uint16_t)(value & 0x0000FFFFU));
    ADF4158_DelayFunc();

    return kStatus_Success;
}
```

Comment: Which parts are being transmitted?

Comment: The first 16 bits

Comment: When you debug, does the first DSPI_MasterWriteDataBlocking call return?

Comment: yes it does return and nothing outputs in the scope